# How to use numpy.savetxt with a structured array that contains an array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Say I have a structured array as follows:

```
a = np.zeros(10,dtype=[('label1',np.int32, 4), ('label2', np.float_)])
```

And I try to save this as a csv file:

```
np.savetxt('output.csv', a, fmt='%d,%d,%d,%d,%f')
```

Python will generate this error:

```
ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %d,%d,%d,%d,%f
```

I haven't been able to create a fmt string that would suit my output. %s won't work for me here as I need the ability specify the format of the float.

Is it possible to create a csv file from this type of structured array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence what `savetxt` does is:

```
for row in arr:
    print(fmt % tuple(row))
```

So the `fmt` has to work with a `row`, or in this case, an element of your array.

```
In [330]: a = np.zeros(10,dtype=[('label1',np.int32, 4), ('label2', np.float_)])
     ...: 
In [331]: a
Out[331]: 
array([([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.), ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.), ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.),
       ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.), ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.), ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.),
       ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.), ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.), ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.),
       ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.)], 
      dtype=[('label1', '<i4', (4,)), ('label2', '<f8')])
In [332]: a[0]
Out[332]: ([0, 0, 0, 0],  0.)
In [333]: tuple(a[0])
Out[333]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0]), 0.0)
```

Nesting the 4 ints in `label1` makes it difficult to come up with a format that works.  It's a matter of how to Python '%' formatting.

```
In [334]: '%s, %f'%_
Out[334]: '[0 0 0 0], 0.000000'
```

If `a` was 5 fields it would be easier

```
In [335]: a = np.zeros(10,dtype='i,i,i,i,f')
In [336]: a
Out[336]: 
array([(0, 0, 0, 0,  0.),....
       (0, 0, 0, 0,  0.)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<f4')])
In [337]: tuple(a[0])
Out[337]: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0)
In [338]: '%d, %d, %d, %d, %f'%tuple(a[0])
Out[338]: '0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000000'
```

I think you need to either 'flatten' the structure of your array, or write a custom `savetxt`.  As I indicated `savetxt` is not fancy.  If you can `print` the array element by element in the format you want, you can write that format to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the response - that makes a lot of sense. It certainly would be easier to stop using the nested array, but my array is more complicated than the example that I've given - it contains many fields, several of which contain nested ints. Would it make sense in this case to abandon the structured array and use a normal array - keeping track of the columns using some other method?

Comment: Depends on what else you are doing with the array(s).  In SO questions, structured arrays are created most often by `genfromtxt` reading a `csv` with a mix of strings and numbers.  It can even create nested ones like this, though I haven't seen that very often.  But for calculations multiple arrays are usually just as useful as structured ones.  You can't do math across fields.